# Invoking function from the 2d array of function pointers

Tags: arrays, c, function, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test1(){ printf("test1\n"); }
void test2(){ printf("test2\n"); }
void test3(){ printf("test3\n"); }
void test4(){ printf("test4\n"); }

void (*hv_ptr[2])() = {test1,test2};
void (*dev_ptr[2])() = {test3,test4};

void (**ptr[2])() = {hv_ptr, dev_ptr};

int main() {

   ptr[0][0];
   ptr[0][1];
   ptr[1][0];
   ptr[1][1];

   return 0;
}
```

I have declared the array of pointers to function pointers. But with this code, functions are not getting called. Kindly let me know what is going wrong here.

Comment: You are missing `()` and thus not actually invoking any functions. That is, needs to be `ptr[0][0]();`

Comment: With a `typeof` extension (a feature in C23) the declaration could be simplified to `typeof(void())* ptr[2][2] = { {test1, test2}, {test3, test4} };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptr` is an array of pointers to pointers to functions, so `ptr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to a function, so `ptr[0][0]` is a pointer to a function.

Thus, in the expression statement `ptr[0][0];`, the expression is just a pointer to a function. It does not contain a function call.

`ptr[0][0]();` is a call to the function pointed to by `ptr[0][0]`.